# Sort/Order pairs of entries in a mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table like:

```
column names:   name1URL | name1PRICE | name2URL | name2PRICE | name3URL | name3PRICE ....
example row:    link1.co       1        link2.co        11      link3.co        4
```

now I want to order this pairs (e.g. name1URL and name1PRICE) by "PRICE" values ascending...

```
URLS       | PRICES
link1.co        1
link3.co        4
link2.co        11
```

Currently I put them in an php array and sort them with array_multisort() function.

I just want to know if there is a faster and elegant MySQL solution for this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post your SQL query

Comment: I just do a mysql_query("Select * FROM datatable"), convert them with a for loop into the new table format and sort them with the array_multisort() function.

Comment: Well come to think of it, your DB is looking really weird, why is everything in 1 row ? I guess the dudes answer below could work and do "ORDER BY table ASC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to get the columns into two columns, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT name1URL AS URL, name1Price AS Price FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name2URL, name2price from table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name3URL, name3price from table1
    ...
) AS t
ORDER BY price
```

Comment: thank you very much! I think this will help! How can I get the values after doing the mysq_query in php?

Comment: @redsunset - I don't know php, but you will have two columns, `URL` and `Price`, just read them after that.

Comment: @redsunset You get them as the variable after "AS" name1URL AS URL so your url is "URL"

Comment: @Innervisions so the first pair after a $result = mysql_fetch_assoc() would be $result["URL"][0] , $result["Price"][0] , and so on?

Comment: @redsunset if you are still using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` then it is time to learn `mysqli` or `pdo`